# Two dimensional array iteration problem, one ghost element created

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to create a two dimensional containing arrays of length <=3. This should be dynamically filled with the following function:

```
  let preppedArray = []
  let currIndex = -1
  let innerIndex = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < props.children.length; i++) {
    if (i%3 === 0) {
      currIndex++
      innerIndex = 0
      preppedArray.push ([currIndex,"dummy"])
      let currElement = props.children[i]
      preppedArray[currIndex][innerIndex] = currElement
    } else{
      innerIndex++
      preppedArray[currIndex][innerIndex] = props.children[i]
    }
  }
```

Oddly, the following is the output:

```
Array(3) [ (3) […], (3) […], (2) […] ]
​
0: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
1: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
2: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
1: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
1: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
2: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
2: Array [ {…}, "dummy" ]
​​
0: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: Card(props)
, key: null, … }
​​
1: "dummy"
​​
length: 2
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

It looks as though the algorithm creates one "ghost" dummy element at the end. However, I do not comprehend why or how to fix it. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not quite clear what you expect `[currIndex,"dummy"]` to do if not to create a dummy element?

Comment: The "dummy" is created so that the according element can be overwritten from "props.children". However, the loop ends incompletely, by creating one dummy element too many. That is exactly the problem.

Comment: It is react because the array being used comes from props.children. It is also impossible to push elements from the array directly into the outer array... for reasons unknown. That's why I had to use the "dummy approach" (See above)

Comment: You don't have to create a dummy *element*. Yes, you need to create all the inner arrays separately - but do that with an empty array: `preppedArray.push([])`!

Comment: Ah that's an idea! I just also found a different, easier solution.

Comment: Well, yes, there's [many simple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/1048572) to your problem, but it appeared that your question came from confusion over how your current code works. If it's still not clear, try `preppedArray.push(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` and observe the output.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a much easier solution using slice:

```
  let preppedArray = []
  let currIndex = -1
  for (let i = 0; i < props.children.length; i++) {
    if (i%3 === 0) {
      currIndex++
      preppedArray.push (props.children.slice(i,i+3))
    } 
  }
```

This creates a two-dimesional array with the desired amount of sub-elements.

Comment: Even better, drop the `if` condition and just replace `i++` by `i+=3`.